Why does the requested path not get executed in this code
I am working on a little project, that sends emails automaticaly to an emailadress.
I am using Spring Boot, with Spring Security.
Basically I have this class:
package com.birthdayz.web;

import com.birthdayz.domain.service.MailSendingService;
import com.birthdayz.domain.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import com.birthdayz.domain.model.User;

@Controller
public class MailController {

    @Autowired
    MailSendingService mailSendingService;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/send")
    public void sendMail(OAuth2AuthenticationToken auth) {
        System.out.println("request to /send success");
        User loggedUser = userService.findUserBy(auth.getPrincipal().getAttribute("login"));

        if (loggedUser == null) {
            System.err.println("Fehler: Kein Benutzer in der Session gefunden.");
        }

        mailSendingService.sendMail(loggedUser);
    }


    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void sendRequest() {
        WebClient.create()
                .get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .scheme("http")
                        .host("localhost")
                        .port(8080)
                        .path("/send")
                        .build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(String.class)
                .doOnError(error -> System.err.println("Fehler beim Abrufen der URL: " + error.getMessage()))
                .doOnNext(response -> System.out.println("Antwort erhalten: " + response))
                .subscribe();
    }
}

My Idea is that I just simply schedule a GET-Request to /send every x seconds. But it doesnt work and I have tried building up the webClient many ways.
When I go to the browser http://localhost:8080/send, the email gets send away like wished.
Can somebody help me udnerstand this problem?

Why this complexity? Why not just use @Scheduled? Why the complexity of a controller, then a webclient to call this etc. If it doesn't send the problem isn't in your controller but in the code that is calling this controller (which you didn't include). But as mentioned imho you are making things overly complex for periodically sending an email.

You cant use @Scheduled on Methods with a parameter and I need OAuth2AuthenticationToken to be injected so i get the user. or what exactly do you mean

Why would you need the token if it needs to be invoked periodically, that doesnt really make sense imho, but alas. Nonetheless the problem is your calling code not the controller.

I really dont understand "your calling code not the controller". im creating a webclient with a get request. it should 100% go to /send and invoke the controller-method. its the same as i would request some API with a JSON file etc.

Well it doesn't hence your problem is the calling code, as when you directly access the URL it is invoked. But I'll back-off now as apparently you aren't taking the advice here.

Your backend is running in 8080, right? but your backend seems to be call it self~

WIthout showing the code that is actually calling the controller it is impossible to give you a solution. I've requested for that code 3 times, but you insist that the error is in the controller (which it is not).

Does your application also send an email when you use Postman, or cURL, or wget or another tool to access localhost:8080/send? It looks like your scheduled task makes a request without OAuth token in a header, so you would then not find a user in the session and not send an email. Furthermore agreed with @M.Deinum that OAuth does not really make sense for a scheduled task, I would consider changing that.

ok let me toell you how i understannd all that: @Scheduled invokes the method periodically itself. so the webclient will be created and sends a get request to sendMail() and send()mail gets executed, hence the controller-method gets invoked.
im not a senior dev for 30 years. i dont know what you mean. you never need to invoke controller-methods anywhere, thats how i leanred spring web mvc.
is that understandable? i need a solution, or do i need to pay for that newbie knowledge...

@Just a student: When i use curl, it doesnt send the email, i dont know why. ill try doing it without the OAuth, but i dont know exatcly how

My bad apparently the code was in there. Did you include @EnableScheduling on your @SpringBootApplication class? Also I would place this in another class and not in the controller (separate the concerns). Next to that your client code doesn't include anything OAuth related so no token and if you do manage to send it will probably be blocked by Spring Security.

yes i have enabled scheduling. i also created another class PeriodicalRequest with the scheduled method. im know trying to save the login in a cookie and get in with @cookievalue

If you don't include information for the token ni your webclient request you can change at the controller level what you want but that isn't going to change a thing. THe cookie or token won't magically appear, you will need to send it.

is the webclient itself correctly build?

The issue seems to be that your endpoint expects an OAuth token, while your scheduled task does not send one. Since OAuth does not really make sense in an automated context, because there is no user to (periodically) log in and/or refresh the token, I would advise you to restructure your code to directly send an email from the scheduled task.
Since you cannot look up a user based on the OAuth token, you'll need to think of another way to determine who should receive an email. Everyone, or a specific, hardcoded user?
@Controller
public class MailController {

    @Autowired
    MailSendingService mailSendingService;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void sendRequest() {
        // example: send an email to a hardcoded user
        var hardcodedUser = userService.findUserById(1);
        mailSendingService.sendMail(hardcodedUser);

        // example: send an email to all users
        var allUsers = userService.findAll();
        for (var user : allUsers) {
            mailSendingService.sendMail(user);
        }
    }
}

Aside from the above, you may want to consider putting this code not in a @Controller, but in a @Component with an apt name.

Indeed, I see that MailSendingService, it can just as easily have an extra method which has the code of the sendRequest() method in it. Alternatively a BulkMailSendingService could be created.
